# How does Amazon Managed Blockchain's QLDB handle permissions for the different orgs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, amazon-qldb, amazon-managed-blockchain

QLDB seems to be this centralized extension built upon the Fabric orderer service that allows you to query a replication of the blockchain network in an SQL-like manner.

With the different orgs on the network, I was wondering how QLDB handles permissions? It wouldn't make sense for every member to have full access to all data in QLDB, so is there some built-in method of access control for specific parts of the data?

Comment: Do you have reference? I don't think it's built on Fabric orderer...

Answer (score 1):

As with all AWS services, permissions are managed by IAM.

With the general availability announcement of QLDB on 9/10/29, we now have the answer to this question from [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon QLDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonqldb.html).

At the time of this writing, the following are the QLDB permissions that you can grant with IAM:

```
CreateLedger
DeleteLedger
DescribeJournalS3Export
DescribeLedger
ExecuteStatement
ExportJournalToS3
GetBlock
GetDiges
GetRevision
InsertSampleData
ListJournalS3Exports        
ListJournalS3ExportsForLedger
ListLedgers         
ListTagsForResource
SendCommand
ShowCatalog
TagResource
UntagResource
UpdateLedger
```

Comment: These are actions that can be performed in qldb on various components of ledger and not permissions, right?